# Uploading Free app and Paid app to Apple AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I've searched for this question but I couldn't find the answer for it anywhere that's why I'm asking it here please bear with me.

I've seen some apps which have advertisements in it and in itunes we can see "Remove Ads $0.99".

My question is how do I do it with my apps? I want to keep that "Remove Ads" option in itunes for customers so that they can remove advertisements and buy my app if they are annoyed by the advertisements.

Do I have to upload 2 different apps to itunes connect like one app with advertisements and the other without advertisements, or is there any option in itunes connect to provide this facility to customers?

Sorry my english is bad. My apologies.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you only need one app. This single app should just be built to have or not have ads dependent on a check for whether or not the user has purchased the ad free addition.

See this for more details: [Using in app purchase to unlock features vs. using free & paid app versions for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717324/using-in-app-purchase-to-unlock-features-vs-using-free-paid-app-versions-for)

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is in-app purchases. Apple has created an entire page full of examples and other resources for this: https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/